# How can I create object from a file in C++?

Tags: c++, fgets

I have my class complex:

```
#include "Complejo.h"
#include <sstream>
Complejo::Complejo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    real = 0;
    imaginary = 0;
}
Complejo::Complejo(int a, int b){
    real = a;
    imaginary = b;
}


Complejo::~Complejo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
std::string Complejo::mostrar()const{
    std::stringstream  s;
    s << real << "+" << imaginary <<"i";
    return s.str();
}
```

And in my `main` I need to read a file (every line has a complex) like this:

> 3 + 5i
>      4 + 2i
>      3 + 3i

and create objects. How can I do that?

Comment: Your are looking for [Seraialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). Also consider writing code using English. I do not know what *Complejo* is, or *mostrar* for that matter.

Comment: "Complejo" means "complex" and "mostrar" means "show" @IInspectable

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this for each line:

```
void Complejo::f(const std::string& line)
{
  std::stringstream  s(line);
  s>>real>>imaginary;
}
```

You can add checks for a legit line etc.

BTW: the `mostrar` function should be able to print negative values like: `-1-1i`, therefore it can be:

```
std::string Complejo::mostrar()const{
    std::stringstream  s;
    s << real << (imaginary >= 0) ? "+" : "" << imaginary <<"i";
    return s.str();
}
```